# Copying formulas in one column and pasting every nth column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy column B which contains thousands of rows with vlook-ups in each row and paste it into every following 3rd column.

I found this code which works but it's pasting as values, I need the vlook-up formulas to be pasted.

```
Sub Sco__copy()

    Dim cpval As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet8")
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B:B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set cpval = .Range("B12:B" & LastRow)

        For colx = 2 To 40 Step 3
            .Range(.Cells(12, colx), .Cells(LastRow, colx)).Value = cpval.Value
        Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: change both `.Value` with `.Formula`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, just change "value" to "formula".

```html
Sub Sco__copy()

    Dim cpval As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet8")
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B:B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set cpval = .Range("B12:B" & LastRow)

        For colx = 2 To 40 Step 3
            .Range(.Cells(12, colx), .Cells(LastRow, colx)).Formula = cpval.Formula
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could help me with "This answer is useful".

Comment: Also a follow up question, the vlook-up uses a reference cell for the reference column so for example the formula in the first column I use it in is: =VLOOKUP(USE!A12,Holdings!$A$12:$T$21333,B$1,FALSE) in this situation B$1 is the number two, I need this formula pasted in the other columns, which the code does, but those each need to reference their respective number in row 1. So for example the vlook-up in column E needs to be =VLOOKUP(USE!A12,Holdings!$A$12:$T$21333,E$1,FALSE) so the fourth parameter needs to change. Is that possible to do in VBA?